# Jquery Ajax .ajaxError event catching errors from different pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

I am trying to show any type of Ajax request response errors through a common dialog just like a common error page. Do we have any option to catch error descriptions from different Ajax calls in different pages and show it with common Ajax error event?

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(){
    alert("error description is :" +"error desc error from xyz page");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make utility wrapper function for ajax error call like

```
 window.ajaxError =function(errorCode, desc,page){
   //error code if needed
   alert("error description is :" +desc+ "from xyz page"+page);
};
```

and in ajax call you can use it.

```
var menuId = $( "ul.nav" ).first().attr( "id" );
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "script.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id : menuId },
    dataType: "html"
});
request.done(function( msg ) {
    $( "#log" ).html( msg );
});
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    window.ajaxError(jqXHR,textStatus,document.URL);
});
```